# VBA - 2nd+ Iteration of Hitting Cancel Doesn't Leave Behind an Empty Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to code something that requests you to put in a certain lot #. If the number you put is not right, then a message box pops up saying to try again or cancel. If you hit try again, it simply loops back to the first question, whereas cancel makes the inputbox = "", and then proceeds to exit the sub, leaving behind an empty cell. The problem is that as of right now, one iteration of putting something in wrong and hitting cancel immediately works, and leaves behind an empty cell. However, if I put a number in, say 33333, click try again and now put 22222 (which is still wrong), and then click cancel this time because I want to get out of the loop, it exits the loop, but leaves behind the "22222" instead of leaving the cell blank.

```
Sub InputNum()

    'input number
    Dim lotData As String

    'requests an input number to be put in
    lotData = InputBox("Scan in Lot #")

    'checks to ensure the number put in is 3 characters long
    If Len(lotData) <> 3 Then
        'error message
        Result = MsgBox("Invalid Lot # Inputed. Must be 3 Characters. Try Again?", vbOKCancel)
        'if cancel is clicked, input number is made blank and sub is exited
        If Result = vbCancel Then
            lotData = ""
            Exit Sub
        'if ok is clicked to try again, recurses to beginning of code again
        Else
            InputNum
        End If
    End If

    'input number is put into current cell
    ActiveCell.Value = lotData

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `vbCancel` you set `lotData` to "" but then exit the sub before setting the cell value. In the other case you call `InputNum` but then do not exit the sub, so it still runs the `ActiveCell.Value = lotData` line.

```
Sub InputNum()

    'input number
    Dim lotData As String

    'requests an input number to be put in
    lotData = InputBox("Scan in Lot #")

    'checks to ensure the number put in is 3 characters long
    If Len(lotData) <> 3 Then
        'error message
        Result = MsgBox("Invalid Lot # Inputed. Must be 3 Characters. Try Again?", vbOKCancel)
        'if cancel is clicked, input number is made blank and sub is exited
        If Result <> vbOK Then
            ActiveCell.Value = ""
        Else
            InputNum
        End If
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = lotData
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub InputNum()

    Dim InputMsg As String  'shown message
    Dim lotData As String   'input number

    InputMsg = "Scan in Lot #"
    Do
        lotData = InputBox(InputMsg)        'ask user to enter lot number
        If Len(lotData) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'pressed cancel, exit macro
        If Len(lotData) = 3 Then Exit Do    'entered valid lot number, exit Do loop
        InputMsg = "Invalid Lot # Inputed. Must be 3 Characters." & Chr(10) & "Scan in Lot #"   'Because invalid lot number was entered, update shown message to include the error
    Loop

    'input number is put into current cell
    ActiveCell.Value = lotData

End Sub
```